# How do you calculate the entanglement entropy of a tensor network?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, computational-physics, spin-chains, tensor-network

I found that the entanglement entropy can be calculated using the Schmidt coefficients of the state, using
$S = -\sum_i|\alpha_i|^2\log(|\alpha_i|^2)$

In the case of tensor networks, does this simply translate to using the lambda vectors for our singular values, i.e, are the $\alpha_i$ just the components of the lambda vectors? If so, do we perform this computation for each component of all the lambda vectors in the chain?

Edit: The lambda vectors are the singular values one gets after the SVD. i.e, I am referring the vectors in the Vidal canonical form $\lambda_i$ in
$\psi = \sum \lambda_\alpha\Gamma_{\alpha\beta} $

Comment: What are "lambda vectors"?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: This is still not precise enough. Which SVD? There are so many canonical forms for MPS. Please try to make the question precise. I think I could answer (guessing what you mean), but this will then be of no use to other users of the site, which is the point.

Comment: I mean that the state is in Vidal canonical form. I have updated the question.

Comment: I'm afraid this is still not very self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Vidal form, $\lambda_i=\alpha_i$.

If you want to know the entanglement entropy across one cut, you have to determine $S$ precisely for the $\lambda_i$ which belong to that cut.